# CoDrone is_ready_to_fly() fails

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have started programming in **python3** (basics and machine learning). I have created below python program that controls a drone (CoDrone from [robolink.com](https://www.robolink.com/codrone/)) in order to practise OOP. The classes are created for this purpose (practice OOP) mainly and therfore I want to keep them. However working with classes brings some complexity and I suspect this might be why the program is not working.

**test.py file:**

```
import CoDrone


class Drone:
    """Parent class with general data."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.drone = CoDrone.CoDrone()
        self.state = ''
        self.flight_state = False

    def get_statuses(self):
        """Get statuses from drone."""
        self.state = 'placeholder'
        self.flight_state = self.drone.is_ready_to_fly()
        return print(f"[info]: General State:\t{self.state}\n" +
                     f"[info]: Flight state:\t{self.flight_state}")


class Connection(Drone):
    """Connection class."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.pair_status = False
        super().__init__()

    def connect_ble(self):
        """Connect drone with BLE board."""
        # For me the BLE board is connected to COM5 port (device management).
        # TODO: Print error when BLE board is not connected.
        print("\nConnecting to drone #7852 on port COM5...")
        self.pair_status = self.drone.pair('7852', 'COM5')

        if self.pair_status:
            print("Drone successfully paired")
        else:
            print("Try again for any drone and on any port")
            self.drone.pair()

    def disconnect_ble(self):
        """Disconnect drone from BLE board."""
        self.drone.disconnect()
        self.pair_status = False


class Flight(Drone):
    """Flight movements class."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def drone_dance(self):
        """Perform dance with drone."""
        self.get_statuses()
        if self.flight_state:  # TODO: Why is the status not TRUE?
            print("Dance!, Dance!, Dance!")
            self.drone.takeoff()
            self.drone.hover(5)
            self.drone.land()
        else:
            print(f"\nDrone is not ready to fly.\n\nCheck:\n" +
                  f"1. Is the drone oriented right-side up?\n" +
                  f"2. Is the drone already flying?")
            while True:
                usri_continue = input("Do you want to try again? (y/n):\n")
                if usri_continue == 'y' or usri_continue == 'Y':
                    self.drone_dance()
                    break
                elif usri_continue == 'n' or usri_continue == 'N':
                    print(f"\n[!!!!]: Program terminated")
                    break
                else:
                    continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DRONE_CONNECT = Connection()
    DRONE_FLIGHT = Flight()

    DRONE_CONNECT.connect_ble()
    DRONE_FLIGHT.drone_dance()
    DRONE_CONNECT.disconnect_ble()
    DRONE_CONNECT.get_statuses()
```

In class: "`Flight(Drone)`", the method: "`drone_dance()`" should make the drone move when the `self.flight_state` is `True`.
However when the variable is checked the status is `False`.

```
def drone_dance(self):
        """Perform dance with drone."""
        self.get_statuses()
        if self.flight_state:  # TODO: Why is the status not TRUE?
            print("Dance!, Dance!, Dance!")
            self.drone.takeoff()
            self.drone.hover(5)
            self.drone.land()
        else:
```

Documentation on [is_ready_to_fly()](http://docs.robolink.com/codrone-library/isreadytofly):

> This function checks whether the drone is ready to fly by returning a
> boolean. The drone is ready to fly if it is oriented right-side up,
> and not flying.

Any idea why `self.flight_state` is `False`, I expect it to be `True` because the drone is paired and upright.

Comment: Probably because `if self.flight_state:  # TODO: Why is the status not TRUE?` should indeed be False before take off, but you want it to be True! ""The drone is ready to fly if it is oriented right-side up, and not flying"" ==> **and NOT flying**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed to code (see below) and now it works.

```
import CoDrone

drone = CoDrone.CoDrone()


class Drone:
    """Parent class with general data."""

    def get_statuses(self):
        """Get statuses from drone."""
        self.state = drone.get_state()
        self.flight_state = drone.is_ready_to_fly()
        return print(f"[info]: General State:\t{self.state}\n" +
                     f"[info]: Flight state:\t{self.flight_state}")


class Connection(Drone):
    """Connection class."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.pair_status = False

    def connect_ble(self):
        """Connect drone with BLE board."""
        # For me the BLE board is connected to COM5 port (device management).
        # TODO: Print error when BLE board is not connected.
        print("\nConnecting to drone #7852 on port COM5...")
        self.pair_status = drone.pair('7852', 'COM5')

        if self.pair_status:
            print("Drone successfully paired")
            self.get_statuses()
        else:
            print("Try again for any drone and on any port")
            drone.pair()

    def disconnect_ble(self):
        """Disconnect drone from BLE board."""
        drone.disconnect()
        self.pair_status = False
        print("Drone is disconnected.")


class Flight(Drone):
    """Flight movements class."""

    def drone_dance(self):
        """Perform dance with drone."""
        Connection().connect_ble()
        if drone.is_ready_to_fly():
            print("Dance!, Dance!, Dance!")
            drone.takeoff()
            self.get_statuses()
            drone.hover(2)
            drone.land()
        else:
            print(f"\nDrone is not ready to fly.\n\nCheck:\n" +
                  f"1. Is the drone oriented right-side up?\n" +
                  f"2. Is the drone already flying?")
            while True:
                usri_continue = input("Do you want to try again? (y/n):\n")
                if usri_continue == 'y' or usri_continue == 'Y':
                    self.drone_dance()
                    break
                elif usri_continue == 'n' or usri_continue == 'N':
                    Connection().disconnect()
                    print(f"\n[!!!!]: Program terminated")
                    break
                else:
                    continue


def main():
    """Execute when program is run, not when imported."""
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            DRONE_FLIGHT = Flight()
            DRONE_FLIGHT.drone_dance()
        except:
            print("[error}: BLE board not connected.")
            while True:
                usri_continue = input("Do you want to try again? (y/n):\n")
                if usri_continue == 'y' or usri_continue == 'Y':
                    main()
                    break
                elif usri_continue == 'n' or usri_continue == 'N':
                    print(f"\n[!!!!]: yProgram terminated")
                    DRONE_CONNECT = Connection()
                    DRONE_CONNECT.disconnect_ble()
                    break
                else:
                    continue


main()
```